# Manually added software repo error

Tags: updates, repositories

I tried to install spotify with a repo but I think I did something wrong. Ever since I did this I can't fetch updates in the App enter- Failed to fetch updates : How to fix corrupt source file *Details :E: Type ‘sudo’ is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
E: The list of sources could not be read*

Thank you for your guidance[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply removing the file should solve your issue.

In Terminal run:
`sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`

I suggest installing it from [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.spotify.Client). Click on the blue 'Install' button and the click the downloaded file.

Comment: Mersi Vlad ! Problem solved !