# Failed to fetch updates. E: the list of sources could not be read and all the apps are missing from the installed list. Any help for a newbie?

Tags: appcenter, sources, error

I'm pretty new to this, so please bear with me.

Here's the error message from AppCentre: :

Type 'Reading' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
E: The list of sources could not be read

Also, when I click on the 'Installed' list, nothing comes up, except the icon for 'Operating System Updates'

Steam was the last app I installed, but that was a few days ago. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/25089/manually-added-software-repo-error. Problem was caused by an invalid .list file in the repositories list.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. Ended up re-installing eos, but i'll know for next time. cheers